# Is there any oracle sql function which will help in presenting time as 24hrs 32 mins 30 secs

Tags: sql, oracle

Is there any oracle sql function which will help in presenting time as currently i am summing up the time  for a column and calculating it in hours.

> Time
>   892.26 (in hours)

requirement

> Time (in same column) 892 hrs 26 min

Please suggest what can be done.

Comment: .26 hours != 26 minutes.  Do you require some sort of date formatting that displays a timestamp?

Comment: I believe there is no such function, but you can format the result yourself, try using something like this (assuming your time sum column is a number): `select trunc(time_sum)||' hrs '||((time_sum-trunc(time_sum))*60)||' min' the_time from the_table`

Comment: @RaúlJuárez is right. There's no such function. Dates are stored in a way different than numbers. Most probably you are trying to process intervals, which are numbers. Perhaps you can use `CAST (... AS INTERVAL day TO second)` but it's still not clear.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps you should reconsider the data model. If you store the time as number like `893.26` and treat it as `892 hours and 26 minutes`, every calculation will be complicated.

You'd better to store the value as minutes only, like `53,546` (minutes), which come from the simple calculation, `893 x 60 + 26`. Then you can add or subtract between the values simply by `+` or `-` and you can represent it as hours and minutes by simple calculation:

```
hours = trunc(value / 60)
minutes = mod(value, 60)
```

This can be done within your SQL:

```
select trunc(value / 60) || ' hrs ' || mod(value, 60) || 'min'
from ...
```

If your smallest tick is second, you should store every values in second. This can make things much more simple than the way you're using now.

Comment: Or perhaps use the [interval](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/sql_elements001.htm#sthref168) datatype.